# How to make div expandable-collapseable to the left on click on button using JAVASCRIPT not by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I have a panel which contains some options as shown in the image :
[image]

There is a arrow button on header , what I am looking for is , if I click on that button it should expand to the left as shown :
[image]

Example : If I have lets suppose 20 options it will open to the left like that showing 5 image in each part and if I again click on it it will collapse like 1st image .

How it could be done using javascript , html and css only provided everything is dynamic in nature. Any help would be appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `flex-flow: column wrap` and `overflow: hidden` to make something like this.

POC:

```js
const expend = document.querySelector(".expend");
const tools = document.querySelector(".tools");
let isExpened = false;

function expendOrRetract() {
  if (isExpened) {
    expend.innerHTML = ">";
    tools.classList.remove("extend");
  } else {
    expend.innerHTML = "<";
    tools.classList.add("extend");

  }
  isExpened = !isExpened;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tools {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tools.extend {
  width: 40px;
}

.expend {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.tool {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="expend" onclick="expendOrRetract()">></div>
<div class="tools">

  <div class="tool">t1</div>
  <div class="tool">t2</div>
  <div class="tool">t3</div>
  <div class="tool">t4</div>
  <div class="tool">t5</div>
  <div class="tool">t6</div>
  <div class="tool">t7</div>
  <div class="tool">t8</div>

</div>
```

you can use `diraction: rtl`
to the left:

```js
const expend = document.querySelector(".expend");
const tools = document.querySelector(".tools");
let isExpened = false;

function expendOrRetract() {
  if (isExpened) {
    expend.innerHTML = "<";
    tools.classList.remove("extend");
  } else {
    expend.innerHTML = ">";
    tools.classList.add("extend");

  }
  isExpened = !isExpened;
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tools {
  direction: rtl;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 30px;
  width: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tools.extend {
  width: 40px;
}

.expend {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: solid 1px;
}

.tool {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="expend" onclick="expendOrRetract()">
  < </div>
    <div class="tools">

      <div class="tool">t1</div>
      <div class="tool">t2</div>
      <div class="tool">t3</div>
      <div class="tool">t4</div>
      <div class="tool">t5</div>
      <div class="tool">t6</div>
      <div class="tool">t7</div>
      <div class="tool">t8</div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Matan Sanbira , Appreciate your answer , But How could I open the list (t5,t6,t7,t8) to the left ??

Comment: Thanks. Matan for the reply